# Slide elements relative to their position with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following function takes an `options` argument to (toggle) slide an element with jQuery:

```
// options
slideRight: {
  direction: 'right',
  startValue: '0',
  endValue: '100px'
},

// function
function(slide) {
  const $el = $(this.el)
  $el.click(() => {
    if ($el.parent().css(slide.direction) === slide.startValue) {
      $el.parent().animate({
        [slide.direction]: slide.endValue
      }, 200)
    } else {
      $el.parent().animate({
        [slide.direction]: slide.startValue
      }, 200)
    }
  })
}
```

I want to add a fourth option called `mirror` which will make another element mirror the movement.

But for this, I need to move the elements relative to their current position. How can I accomplish this?

(Note: the elements have their `position` set as `fixed`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is a little different from the ones posted so far but should work as a starting point for what you want. I used `transform` to do the relative positioning, since if you have an element positioned already with `top left`, `transform: translate` will move your item relative to its fixed current position. I think animating transform has an added performance benefit as well. I'd look into that.

Modified your code a bit based on (incorrect I'm sure) assumptions to work in the demo:

```
const someObject = {    

    // function
    slide: function (slide) {
      const $el = $(slide.el)
      $el.click(() => {
        if (slide.slideRight.direction === 'right') {

            $el.parent().animate({transform: 'translateX(' + slide.slideRight.endValue + 'px)'}, {
                duration: 200,
                step: function (now, fn) {
                    fn.start = $el.hasClass('in') ? slide.slideRight.endValue : slide.slideRight.startValue;
                    fn.end = $el.hasClass('in') ? slide.slideRight.startValue : slide.slideRight.endValue;
                    $el.parent().css({transform: 'translateX(' + now + 'px)'});

                    if (now === fn.end) {
                        $el.toggleClass('in');
                    }
                }
            })

        } else {
          // other stuff
        }
      })
    }

}

someObject.slide({
    el: '.position-me',
    slideRight: {
        direction: 'right',
        startValue: 0,
        endValue: 100,
        mirror: '.position-me-parent-mirror'
    }
})
```

**[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/zLv7cbtp/)**

Answer (score 2):

Check if this might work. I have added 4th option `mirror` and then given the same animation to it as given to first element. Not sure if the handle is correct or not as I don't have complete markup.

```
// options
slideRight: {
  direction: 'right',
  startValue: '0',
  endValue: '100px',
  mirror: '#mirrorElement'
},

// function
function(slide) {
  const $el = $(this.el)
  $el.click(() => {
    if ($el.parent().css(slide.direction) === slide.startValue) {
      $el.parent().animate({
        [slide.direction]: slide.endValue
      }, 200);
      $(slide.mirror).animate({
        [slide.direction]: slide.endValue
      }, 200);
    } else {
      $el.parent().animate({
        [slide.direction]: slide.startValue
      }, 200)
      $(slide.mirror).animate({
        [slide.direction]: slide.startValue
      }, 200);
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When passing your argument to `.animate()` you can set `right: "-=50px"` in order to slide the element 50px to the right of it's current `right` value.

Something like this will move two elements the same amount relative from their current position:

```
function slide(startValue, endValue) {
    var change = endValue-startValue;
    $("#one").animate({right:"-="+change+"px"}, 200);
    $("#two").animate({right:"-="+change+"px"}, 200)  
}

slide(0,50)
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uLv1mz2u/

Is this what you are looking for?